# remove string after [ character using shell script?

Tags: shell

I have a file containing string like:
./intercompany.rb[1:1]            | passed | 9 minutes 7 seconds    |

I want to remove the string coming after [ character.
Output should be ./intercompany.rb

How can we do this in shell script??

Answer (score 0):

```
s='./intercompany.rb[1:1] | passed | 9 minutes 7 seconds |'
echo "${s%%[*}"
```

See http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe and/or [BashFAQ #100](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100).

Answer (score 0):

With `sed`:

```
sed 's/\[.*//' < file
```